# Multilanguage and multitheme at same time

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that has multilanguage support (using the */res/values-*** way) with success. Then I want to use Holo and falling legacy devices (2.3.* for example) to use the default one (using the */res/values-v11* way).

So, I end up with a structure similar to this one (the one without language is EN, as default):

- /res/values
- /res/values-v11
- /res/values-de
- /res/values-de-v11
- /res/values-es
- /res/values-es-v11

... where in each one I have the following:

- strings.xml
- themes.xml

... where *strings.xml* is where the localised text are defined, and *themes.xml* has:

For *non-v11* directories (legacy devices)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <!-- Any customizations for your app running on pre-3.0 devices here -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

For *-v11* directories (+3.0 devices)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <!-- Any customizations for your app running on devices with Theme.Holo here -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Remembering to add this attribute into the application tag on AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:theme   ="@style/MyTheme"
```

This is working in all languages and all devices, current and legacy, with correct theme picking and everything. Tested in several physical devices.

**So, the question:**

Don't you think that this is heavily maintainable? I mean, then we have 2 string.xml files for every language which are exactly identical, but for every new text we have to fill it twice, increasing the risk of typos. The same happens if you have *analytics.xml*, *styles.xml*, ... inside

Having the language handling so nice in Android using *strings.xml*, is there any other workaround to have this working multitheme and multilanguage in a nicer way?

Thank you.

Comment: This is just a note, but if the duplicate files really are supposed to be identical you could just modify one and then overwrite the other with the changed one, avoiding having to modify both.

Comment: Hey can you send the github link of this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why do you need something like

```
values-de-v11
```

I would just use something like this:

```
values
values-de
values-fr
values-es
values-cat
...
```

And put inside every strings.xml file with the translation.
On the other hand you can also add the folders:

```
values
values-v11
```

And inside you can add your themes.

The folder values should have both the strings.xml for the default language (usually english) and the fallback theme file for devices without holo.

You can check all the possibilites in the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: Then, _values_ folder contains the _strings.xml_ for default language **AND** _themes.xml_ with the fallback theme for legacy devices, and _values-v11_ **ONLY** contains the _themes.xml_ with the Holo theme, right?

Comment: @Xavi yes, that's it. And the same for the other resources (hdpi, xhdpi...). values folder should have all the default resources for your app, and you should always provide at least a default version of every kind of them (this is, a default language, a default screen resolution, etc.).

Comment: thank you very much. This evening I'll do the change and I'll provide feedback :-)

Comment: I did the changes, tested and all OK. I must say that this applies also to _analytics.xml_ and _styles.xml_ , so the **values** folder contains **ALL** default XML files, and you can create a _values-[modifier]_ separatedly with all files that should overwrite the defaults, like strings for localisation, theming, or whatever. Thank you very much to @Esparver ! :D

Comment: You cannot do like this because in the link that you have mentioned has said that    " When appending multiple qualifiers, you must place them in the same order in which they are listed in table 2. If the qualifiers are ordered wrong, the resources are ignored."