# Android: How to use different themes for different android versions?

Tags: android, themes, manifest

MinSDKVersion = 7
TargetSDKVersion = 17

If the user have SDKVersion 11 or higher I like to set the theme to Theme.Holo.Light.
It doesn't works for me here. When I launch the app on a 3.1 device it just uses the Theme.Light:

[image]

Same when I run this app on a device with lower version than 3.1

My Folderstructure:

[image]

Manifest:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
```

values-v11:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>


<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Any customizations for your app running on devices with Theme.Holo here -->
</style>
```

other values folders:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <!-- Any customizations for your app running on devices with Theme.Holo here -->
</style>
```

How can I use this correctly?

Sincerely
Marco Seiz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you have your theme twice in your styles.xml file?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>


<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Any customizations for your app running on devices with Theme.Holo here -->
</style>
```

Delete the one you don't need(In this case the Theme.Light theme):

values-v11:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Any customizations for your app running on devices with Theme.Holo here -->
</style>
```

values:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <!-- Any customizations for your app running on devices with Theme.Holo here -->
</style>
```

Comment: I did that but it still showed the old theme and not the holo theme on my android 4.1 AND 3.1 device

Comment: Did you delete the duplications?

Comment: Yep I did. I figured out the error. I had to create two folders for one language. For german: values-de AND values-de-v11 and same for english... It works now :) Thanks for your helps and tips!

Answer (score 2):

Place the solution provided by @Ahmad in new files called *themes.xml* on the directories he said :-)

If you'll use multilanguage and multithemes, you can take a look at a similar question I did some minutes before... and got answered:

[Multilanguage and multitheme at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334498/multilanguage-and-multitheme-at-same-time/14334844#14334844)