# Progress Bar Theme Style Android

Tags: android, layout, styles, themes, progress-bar

i'm confused about deploying my android apps, theming isue.

How can i display on diferent devices a progress bar(for example) with his native theme? So if its android 4.0 display it with themes for 4.0 and if its android 2.2 display it with themes for 2.2...beause if i develop for android 2.2, i get his theme on other devices versions.

i get this always

[image]

I want this for other versions.

[image]

EDIT

If the device has version 2.2 i want that progress bar as a 2.2 progress bar android version. But if it's a 4.0 version i want a 4.0 progress bar style verion. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The effect below is one of features of theme Holo, which is introduced into android since 4.0. So there is possibility you can get such layout effect by introducing style file into lower version of system. See [set-holo-theme-in-older-android-versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649634/set-holo-theme-in-older-android-versions)

Comment: That's not what i want. I've explained it wrong. If the device has version 2.2 i want that progress bar as a 2.2 progress bar android version. But if it's a 4.0 version i want a 4.0 progress bar style verion. Is that possible? ( without compile for every version )

Comment: By default a dialog's theme is same with its poster, but you can pass an resource id of the theme to the dialog builder's constructor. So you need to create a xml value that describes the theme you want, which is platform-dependent. See [android-how-to-use-different-themes-for-different-android-versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335453/android-how-to-use-different-themes-for-different-android-versions)